# JSON Return show function detail() { [native code] }

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used a polling script in my user.php page which get new event(if) from upsidenew.php page with long polling JS.

Now my Question, Why my script show return result:  function detail() { [native code] }

please see my code below; Here is my complete code for polling.

My Sql Table name: updateside

```
id - work_id - parent_id - from_id - to_id - sub - detail - img - created
..........................................................................

AI - work_id, parent_id etc. all data collect by user post form
```

In my upsidenew.php page:

```
$parent = $row['parent_id']; // collect from above query
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Dhaka');
$timestamp = date("M j, y; g:i a", time() - 2592000);

$u = mysqli_query($dbh,"SELECT * FROM updateside WHERE `parent_id`='".$parent."' AND `created` > '".$timestamp."' ORDER BY created DESC") or die(mysqli_error($dbh));
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($u)) {
$result['from_id'] = $row['from_id'];
$result['parent_id'] = $row['parent_id'];
$result['detail'] = $row['detail'];
.....
...
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($result);
exit;
}
```

And at user.php page my JavaScript:

```
    function waitForMsg(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "upsidenew.php",
        async: true, 
        cache: false, 
        timeout:50000, 
        datatype: 'json',
success: function(data){ 
        if(data) {
        $("#updatetime").html('<div class="upbox1" id=" '+ parent_id + '"> ' + data.detail + '</div>');
        }
setTimeout(
                waitForMsg, /* Request next message */
                1000 /* ..after 1 seconds */
            );
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
            addmsg("error", textStatus + " (" + errorThrown + ")");
            setTimeout(
                waitForMsg, /* Try again after.. */
                15000); /* milliseconds (15seconds) */
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
            waitForMsg(); /* Start the inital request */
});
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Ok.sir I edit my question above to clear

Comment: Your ajax request is pointing to upsidenew.php instead of update.php, is that correct?

Comment: Your `url` parameter (`upsidenew.php`) does not seem to match the location of your `update.php` file. Is that just an oversight pasting the code in SO or am I missing something else?

Comment: @Ragnar: sorry for the repeat: guess we answered at the same time, :-)

Comment: Sorry sir, edit again, update.php is my writing mistake. sorry

Comment: It's still unclear what you mean. What exactly is happening and where are you seeing that "return result"?

Comment: Your while statement in your `upsidenew.php` file is not properly closed (missing `}`).

Comment: Ok sir, in my #updatetime div show Ajax return result:" function detail() { [native code] } " and it append same think one after one

Comment: @ Marventus ok, after correction, Its show same result also.

Comment: If that's what's happening it's likely you're not calling the function, e.g., you're seeing the function reference.

Comment: Can you please post the JSON that the browser receives? We cannot reproduce without your database.

Comment: edit: add table structure and here all my polling script. Thank u sir.

Comment: what kind of data is stored in the sql table 'detail' field ?

Comment: All data collect by user post form